# Why Maxwell Distribution of Velocities curve is Bell Shaped? Is there any intuitive and/or quantum mechanical reason behind it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

Why Maxwell Distribution of Velocities curve is Bell Shaped?

Apart from mathematics,

1. Is there any intuitive reason behind it?
2. Is there any quantum mechanical reason behind it?
3. Is there any explanation with which we can imagine the necessity of distribution to be Bell Shaped?

[image]

Comment: That is not bell-shaped. This was derived by Maxwell, so clearly not dependent on quantum mechanics. What is Gaussian, are the velocities along a single axis (for example $v_x$), centered around $0$.

Comment: @sammygerbil That question is related but not the same as the present. In that case the problem is mainly the evolution with temperature of MB distribution. Here, it is its qualitative shape, whatever is the temperature.